# Write txt file with 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, file

Well, I need to create a txt file with this output, but I'm struggling to do that, So I'm asking some suggestions on how i do that, I'm thinking of doing a 2d array of char,is this the better way? Thanks anyway.

Output:

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  
                     6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6  
                     3 0 3 8 5 9 6 0 3 2 0 4 8 5 4 3 9 6 8 4 5 0 4 3 4 3 2 4 9 8 5 4 9 6 4 5  
                     3 0 3 8 5 9 6 0 3 2 0 4 8 5 4 3 9 6 8 4 5 0 4 3 4 3 2 4 9 8 5 4 9 6 4 5  
                     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Reference            A T G C T G C A A T G C A T G C A A C G T A C T A G A T C A T A C T T A  
IFTTM3-1-111_H04_004 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . C .  
MT-04PI-F1_E07_001   C A . . 1C. . . . C C . . . . . . . . . . G . . . . . . . . . T . . . .  
                             2T
```

Comment: first accept some answers.

Comment: it's hard to tell. Without code i might even advice you to use StringBuilder to make lines out of integer generator - sometimes it can be simple solution too.

Comment: Try to look in this question:
[Writing a string and 2D Array to a .txt file - Java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945960/writing-a-string-and-2d-array-to-a-txt-file-java

Comment: Not construtive. See [ask]?

Answer (score 3):

Not clear what the lower part means, but as for number matrix, there is a one line solution (inefficient though)

```
    int[][] a = { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 } };
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(a).replace("], ", "\n").replaceAll("[\\[,\\]]", ""));
```

output

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
```

If you want to iterate over your 2d yourself, then just go java.utl.Arrays.deepToString(int[]) src, copy paste the code and fix it according to your needs.

**BTW** There are many things in Arrays we can use as a reference. E.g. if you are not sure how to write good equals() or hashCode() go to a corresponding Arrays method there you will know how. See who the authors are: Josh Bloch, Neal Gafter, John Rose.

Comment: Thanks, this code helped me alot, i'll try to code a little more and post something, the code i have now isn't good enough